# Page Profile Picture With Facebook API

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

This is my code:

```
$this->session = new Facebook\FacebookSession(ACCESS_TOKEN); 
$response_pic = (new Facebook\FacebookRequest(
$this->session, 'GET', '/'.ID_PAGE.'/picture'))->execute()->getGraphObject();
var_dump($response_pic);
```

The `var_dump` result is:

```
object(Facebook\GraphObject)#19 (1) { ["backingData":protected]=> array(0) { } }
```

I need get the profile picture, but the response is:

> "backingData":protected

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You can use picture as a field of a page so the request could be :

```
$response_pic = (new Facebook\FacebookRequest(
$this->session, 'GET', '/'.ID_PAGE, ['fields' => 'picture'])->execute()->getGraphObject()
```